# What is the Purpose of chunkFilename of mini-css-extract-plugin Module?

Tags: webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm using mini-css-extract-plugin module now, and setting its chunkFilename value and make sure the value of `"[id].css"` by running it.
However, I couldn't see the file.

The reference is below.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#minimal-example

So, my questions is,

What is the chunkFilename of mini-css-extract-plugin?

What is the purpose of chunkFilename?

How can you see the file?

Answer (score 31):

In webpack's terminology a chunk is an asset that should not be bundled with everything else in one file but should be somehow separated. I guess in your code you don't import asynchronously your styles or have any special `splitChunks` configuration. That instructs webpack to simply put every css in a file, so the `chunkFilename` option remains unused.

Check below some examples (that I am aware of) that can create some chunks.

#### Example 1

```js
// App.js
import './a.css';
import './b.css';
import './c.css';
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //... other configs
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: 'chunk-[id].css',
    })
  ]
}
```

Here we will simply get in the dist folder a `main.css` file containing `a,b,c` styles. `chunkFilename` remains unused in this scenario.

#### Example 2

```js
// App.js
import './a.css';
import ( /* webpackChunkName: "my-special-style" */ './b.css');
import './c.css';
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //... other configs
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: 'chunk-[id].css',
    })
  ]
}
```

In this setup now, that we use the `async import` we will end up inside dist folder again with a `main.css` that now contains only `a,c` styles and a new file called `chunk-my-special-style.css` that is basically `b.css`. As you understand `b.css` is a `chunk` now thus it has all the capabilities that webpack provides like `chunkFilename`.

#### Example 3

```js
// App.js
import './a.css';
import './b.css';
import './c.css';
```

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //... other configs
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
    }]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'ultra-special-styles',
          test: /c\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: 'chunk-[id].css',
    })
  ]
}
```

In this setup now, we use the `splitChunks` configuration. As the name suggests we have the ability to create our own chunks based on some conditions (regex,functions,etc...). Although these files will not be imported asynchronously  is very important to use these optimizations in order not to bloat our files, either js or css. In this example we will end up in dist folder, again with a `main.css` file that contains `a,b` styles and `chunk-ultra-special-styles.css` that is basically `c.css`. Inside the `splitChunks` option we specify the name of the chunk (like we did above with a comment) and a regular expression to match the desired files that should be on a seperate chunk/file. Everything else is being handled internally by webpack's and MiniCssExtractPlugin's magic!